# How to populate gridviews from code behind using Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, dotnetnuke

I am working with asp.net with DotNetNuke.

And I want to try something that is going to help me in my other real project.

I want to fill a GridView from code behind using Stored Procedures in sql server ?

1. in the Info component I add this:

   `public string Emri2 { get; set; }`
2. in the DataProvider I add this:

   `public abstract IDataReader GetEmri(string Emri);`
3. in the Controller I add this:

   ```
    public GradesInfo GetEmri(GradesInfo gr)
   {

       return (GradesInfo)CBO.FillObject(DataProvider.Instance().GetEmri(gr.Emri2), typeof(GradesInfo));

   }
   ```
4. in SqlDataProvider I add this:

   ```
   public override IDataReader GetEmri(string Emri)
   {
       return (IDataReader)SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(ConnectionString, "SelektoStudentet", Emri);
   }
   ```

How to make it that on the page load the grid is going to be filled ?

On pageLoad:

`GradesController gr = new GradesController();`

`GradesInfo grIn = new GradesInfo();`

`grIn.Emri2 = "John";`

`gr.GetEmri(grIn);`

can someone help em please? I have tried many thing but I can't do it

P.s. I am not allowed to use SqlConnection, SqlCommand etc..

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a grid, you will want to work with a slightly different return type I'm guessing as you are getting multiple records.

Your SqlDataProvider is fine.  But in the controller you want the return to be `List<GradesInfo>`.

Then use `CBO.FillCollection<GradesInfo>(DataProvider.Instance().GetEmri("yourvaluehere"));`

Then, in the ascx you can do the following, assuming that you are using a datagrid with an id of dgrData.

```
var controller = new GradesController();
dgrData.DataSource = controller.GetEmri("yourvaluehere");
dgrData.DataBind();
```